# Using ThinStuff to allow multiple sessions in XP

Tags: windows-xp, remote-desktop

How does the [Thinstuff](http://www.thinstuff.com/) product work to allow multiple terminal sessions in XP?

Is it against the Microsoft EULA?

Comment: Link/more info required please.

Comment: Just google ThinStuff: http://lmgtfy.com/?q=thinstuff